# Create a new column in MySQL that is a shifted version of another column, with a null row?

Tags: mysql

I think that this is best asked using an example.

say that my original table is called origin and is

```
+-------+-------+------+
| list  | type  | date |
+-------+-------+------+
| a1    | a     | 1    |
| a2    | a     | 2    |
| a3    | a     | 3    |
| a4    | a     | 4    |
| a5    | a     | 5    | 
| a6    | a     | 6    |
| ...   | ...   | ...  |
| a(n-1)| a     | (n-1)|
| an    | a     | n    |
| b1    | b     | 1    |
| b2    | b     | 2    |
| b3    | b     | 3    |
| b4    | b     | 4    |
| b5    | b     | 5    | 
| b6    | b     | 6    |
| ...   | ...   | ...  |
+-------+-------+------+
```

and I want to add a column called list_shifted(list_s) where

```
+-------+-------+-------+------+
|list_s | list  | type  | date |
+-------+-------+-------+------+
| NULL  | a1    | a     | 1    |
|  a1   | a2    | a     | 2    |
|  a2   | a3    | a     | 3    |
|  a3   | a4    | a     | 4    |
|  a4   | a5    | a     | 5    | 
|  a5   | a6    | a     | 6    |
| ...   | ...   | ...   | ...  |
|a(n-2) | a(n-1)| a     | (n-1)|
|a(n-1) | an    | a     | n    |
| NULL  | b1    | b     | 1    |
|  b1   | b2    | b     | 2    |
|  b2   | b3    | b     | 3    |
|  b3   | b4    | b     | 4    |
|  b4   | b5    | b     | 5    | 
|  b5   | b6    | b     | 6    |
| ...   | ...   | ...   | ...  |
+-------+-------+-------+------+
```

is there a simple way to do this

Answer (score 0):

It looks like both the columns `list` and `list_s` are dependent on the other two.

I would question the need for either of these columns, you can always build the column you require when you query the data.

For `list`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(type,date) list
  FROM origin
```

For `list_s`:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN date - 1 > 0 THEN CONCAT(type,date - 1)
         ELSE NULL
       END CASE list_s
  FROM origin
```

Answer (score 0):

here is two query that could solve your problem.

First one if your date column is increased by 1 in every next row (for every type) like you post in you question example from 1 to 5 it's always 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 then you can simple make one RIGHT JOIN like this:

```
SELECT ts.list, tx.*
FROM (SELECT `list`, type, `date`
      FROM t1) AS ts
RIGHT JOIN t1 AS tx
ON ts.type = tx.type AND ts.date = (tx.date - 1);
```

Second one is solution if date is not in the exact order (if some row is deleted or something like this) and numbers from 1 to 5 not necessary to have all of them like 1, 2, 5... Then you can use temporary variables (it can be used in first case of course but query is a little bit complicated) like this.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN type_s = type THEN list_s ELSE null END AS list_s, `list`, type, `date`
FROM (SELECT @prev AS list_s, @prev := tx.list AS `list`, 
             @prevTyp AS type_s, @prevTyp := tx.type AS type, tx.date
      FROM (SELECT @prev := null) AS i, (SELECT @prevTyp := null) AS y, t1 AS tx
      ORDER BY tx.type, tx.date) AS myTable;
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4760f/10) for both query to see how it's work.

**NOTE** that the one row when value is inserted is commented. I do that so you can see where is the 'problem' with the first query! (if you uncomment it will work as in your desired result).

GL!

P.S. if you have any question fill free to ask in comment below...